# Hide out of stock - "pre_get_post" taxanomy for visibility on shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, visibility, product

In my WooCommerce store, I have "Hide out of stock items from the catalogue" enabled. This option causes **product variations on individual pages to become invisible**.

I want to apply "Hide out of stock items from the catalogue" option **only on archive pages (search, categories)**.

Here is my code:

```
function featured_posts( $query ) {
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() ) return;

    //What goes in here?
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'featured_posts' );
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try This

You have to check page for do this as follow

```
function featured_posts( $query ) {

    if(is_product_category() || is_search()){
        if ( ! $query->is_main_query() ){
            return;
        }
    }
    ....
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'featured_posts' );
```

Comment: Hi, I'm too tired to explain what's actually happening. I will come back to this tomorrow and explain my question clearly.